# Microphone volume level using Adobe Flash on mac is not the same as shown by OS

Tags: macos, actionscript-3, flash, microphone

I've implemented a microphone volume meter - using Adobe Flash.
It displays the **activityLevel** property.

On Windows 10 - it reflects the volume level as shown by the OS ("recording devices" panel), but on Mac it doesn't.

I'm aware to the fact that the user has control on different recording settings (using the "recording devices" panel and even the Flash settings).

My question - is it possible to display a "reliable" volume level - which will reflect the actual recording level - as the operating system shows it?

Comment: It's not possible to "read" the OS meter levels. There are different algorithms to measure such a thing. It's possible that by coincidence Microsoft and Adobe are using same formula (RMS? Peak-to-Peak?) whilst Apple uses a different one (later you might find even Android uses yet another different method too). **Don't worry about it**. At least your app will be consistent no matter what the platform it runs on.